# Editing a datatable and sending it back to a database

Tags: c#

With my program I have a datatable that gets populated with records fetched from a database. This is displayed in a datagrid view and when a cell is clicked it loads all the values into textboxes. When a save button is clicked it will then save the textbox values back into the datatable. However how can I send this datatable back to the database and have it update the records?

Here is my code to load the records:

```
 indexRow = e.RowIndex;
        DataGridViewRow row = dgv_ReturnSearch.Rows[indexRow];

        tb_editFirstName.Text = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        tb_editLastName.Text = row.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        tb_editAge.Text = row.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
        tb_editPostCode.Text = row.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
        tb_editMobNum.Text = row.Cells[5].Value.ToString();
        tb_editEmail.Text = row.Cells[6].Value.ToString();
        tb_editAllergies.Text = row.Cells[7].Value.ToString();
        tb_editDOB.Text = row.Cells[8].Value.ToString();
        tb_editGender.Text = row.Cells[9].Value.ToString();
```

Here is my code to save them

```
DataGridViewRow newDataRow = dgv_ReturnSearch.Rows[indexRow];
            newDataRow.Cells[1].Value = tb_editFirstName.Text;
            newDataRow.Cells[2].Value = tb_editLastName.Text;
            newDataRow.Cells[3].Value = tb_editAge.Text;
            newDataRow.Cells[4].Value = tb_editPostCode.Text;
            Logic.SQLQueriesUtility.Adapter.Update(dt);
```

However this doesn't actually update the database, only the local datatable. When it is loaded again all the changes revert.

Thanks

Comment: Doesn't work **HOW**?  Throws an error?  Doesn't update?  Spikes your coffee?

Comment: Ah yeah sorry, edited the main post to make it clearer.

Comment: If you're using `DataTable` then you need to use `DataAdapter` (and `DataSet`) in order to use the two-way data support in ADO.NET, however please note that the `DataTable` (and the related "Strongly-typed DataSets") paradigm date from the original .NET Framework 1.x, and were replaced with the superior Entity Framework in .NET 3.5, so if this is a new project, please consider switching to EF.

Comment: can you post the full code for your load and save ? did you use any sql commands to bind the grid on load/save ?

Comment: That is all the code for the load and save, there is only the code for binding the datagrid to the datatable here: `dt.Clear();
                customerSQL.SearchAllCustomer();

                Logic.SQLQueriesUtility.Adapter.Fill(dt);

                dgv_ReturnSearch.DataSource = dt;

                dt.AcceptChanges();`

And here is the SQL statement `SELECT * FROM customer_info;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I managed to fix it by doing:

```
DataGridViewRow newDataRow = dgv_ReturnSearch.Rows[indexRow];
            dt.Rows[indexRow]["first_name"] = tb_editFirstName.Text;
            dt.Rows[indexRow]["last_name"] = tb_editLastName.Text;
            dt.Rows[indexRow]["age"] = tb_editAge.Text;
            dt.Rows[indexRow]["postcode"] = tb_editPostCode.Text;
            dt.Rows[indexRow]["mobile_num"] = tb_editMobNum.Text;
            dt.Rows[indexRow]["email"] = tb_editEmail.Text;
            dt.Rows[indexRow]["allergies"] = tb_editAllergies.Text;
            dt.Rows[indexRow]["DOB"] = tb_editDOB.Text;
            dt.Rows[indexRow]["gender"] = tb_editGender.Text;
            Logic.SQLQueriesUtility.Adapter.Update(dt);
```

Instead of what I was doing before, now it works perfectly and any changes are saved back to the database.

Answer (score 0):

To load a `gridview` with data from the database you'll need to use `DataTable` and `DataAdapter` then bind the grid. it should look something like this:

```
private void CustomersBindGrid()
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(mycon))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Customers";
            cmd.Connection = con;

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                sda.Fill(dt);
                Gridview1.DataSource = dt;
                Gridview1.DataBind();
            }
        }
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Try updating the database directly:

```
private void SaveEdits_Click()
{
 using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(mycon))
        {
            con.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Customers set firstname= @FN , lastname= @LN , age = @AG , postcode= @PC where CustomerID = @CustID";
                cmd.Connection = con;

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustID", cid);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FN", tb_editFirstName.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LN", tb_editLastName.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AG", tb_editAge.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PC", tb_editPostCode.Text);

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        CustomersBindGrid();
        MessageBox.show("Information Updated!");
   }
}
```

You need to edit this update command to your columns in the database and get a way to read the customer id so the condition actually work and update the database.

Comment: Yeah that is what I do, but I guess its not clear in my code because there is a separate class which runs the SQL. The data table loads fine, and if I edit the cells actually in the data grid view and then run the update command, it will update them properly in the database, however it doesn't when I try to edit the rows using the text boxes

Comment: @SamSims The textboxes are inside the gridview or seperated and you want to update the gridview row from a textbox outside the gridview ?

Comment: Yeah, like this https://gyazo.com/0f7a03c2f4cba2f64a64ccaff04a9744
The problem is when I come to pushing the datatable back to the database using dt.Update. It wont update the new values, even though they change in the datagrid view

Comment: @SamSims let me know if this helps

Answer (score 0):

In your posting, you don't write, how your client is developed...
Normally, this would be done with a SQL update command.
Therefore (in the Microsoft universe) the SqlClient (System.Data.SqlClient Namespace) can be used.
As soon as the user press the save button, you overtake the relevant textbox.text values in variables, change datatypes if necessary, generate an SQL update string to update the data on your SQL server.
Example SQL update string:

```
Update TableName set ColumnName1Text = 'some text', ColumName2Integer = 12, ColumnName.... = ... where ColumnNameKey = KeyToDatatable
```

Then you submit the SQL command (SQL update string) to the SQL server via SqlClient (SqlCommand).
But therefore you need a unique key for the where clause (in the example KeyToDatatable) so that only the row with the key is updated.
The key normally is queried from the DataTable (with the other fields) to show the data (in your grid) and then taken over to the update command (can be "hided" from the user, that don't has to know the key).